# Duda con pasar valor de php a javascript

Tags: php, javascript, post

En la pagina que abajo muestro estoy llamando a un php para que me pase el valor de un campo. Cuando hago onclick en una fila de mi tabla el proceso funciona correctamente, me trae el campo comentario.

En un segmento HTML tengo tambien un boton , que necesito funcione en la misma forma, pero no lo he logrado , el archivo cumplir_alerta.php me retorna undefined .

index.php

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function cumplir_alerta(id_entabla) {
        var num_id2 = id_entabla;
            
            if (num_id2 != "") {
                $.post("cumplir_alerta.php", {valorBusqueda: num_id2},
                function(mensaje) {                        
                    $("#comentario1").css('text-align','center');
                        $("#comentario1").html(mensaje);
                }); 
            };
        };  

    <script>

    <div id="fade" class="overlay"></div>
    <div id="light" class="modal">
        <p id="comentario1"></p>
        <p id="botones_alerta">
        <input type='button' value='Cumplido' id='cumplido' onclick="cumplir_alerta(<?=$id?>);">
        <input type='button' value='Leído' id='leido' onclick="javascript:vw_nomostrar();"></p>
    </div>

    <?php
    while (($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result))!=NULL){
        $id=trim($fila['id']);
        $vsocio=trim($fila['numero_socio']);
        $vcomentarios=trim($fila['observaciones']);

        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "    <td align='center'>". $vsocio . "</td>\n";
        echo "    <td align='left'>" .substr($vnombre . ", " . $vapellido,0,30) . "</td>\n";

        if (strlen($vcomentarios) == 0 || $vcomentarios === '-'){
            echo "    <td align='center'><input type=\"button\" value=\"     \" id=\"Ver2\" onclick=\"javascript:buscar('".$id."')\";></td>\n";
        }else{
            echo "    <td align='center'><input type=\"button\" value=\"Ver\" id=\"Ver\" onclick=\"javascript:buscar('".$id."')\";></td>\n";
        }
    ?>
```

cumplir_alerta.php

```html
<?php
    $consultaBusqueda = $_POST['valorBusqueda'];
    $mensaje="OK ... EL ID ES " . $consultaBusqueda;
    echo nl2br($mensaje);
?>
```

Este ultimo lo armé como para mostrar lo necesario. Que estoy haciendo mal ?

Comment: Agrego que el problema es en :

<input type='button' value='Cumplido' id='cumplido' onclick="cumplir_alerta(<?=$id?>);">

Comment: intenta con onclick="cumplir_alerta(<? echo $id; ?>);">

Comment: Gracias. Creo que el problema ademas de lo que me propones, es el paso de la variable , queda vacía. En el bucle while cargo una tabla (alli es php) , en el boton ( html) estoy queriendo pasar una variable que proviene de la fila en la que previamente hice click ... me parece que no la toma .. y no como solucionarlo ..

Comment: El boton esta dentro de tu tabla o es un boton independiente ?¿

Comment: es independiente . Con el while muestro la tabla , toco un boton que me abre un modal en CSS con un campo que llamo y trae correctamente. En esa pantallita modal tengo un boton para hacer el update de 1 dato llamando a otro php , ahi no puedo conseguir la variable

Comment: el modal a donde direcciona ?

Comment: Ah ya, ahora entiendo pues en el contexto del modal no existe tu variable $id porque esta fuera del PHP

Comment: me parecia, porque no tenia forma de ver el contenido, se perdia. Como te parece podria tomar esa variable desde el paso anterior, que es donde yo clickeo en el registro que necesito ?

Comment: si en el modal ejecutas bien y haces el update bien, es por que si llego la variable, entonces, lo que debes hacer entonces un input oculto y mandar el id

Comment: pense que como el modal esta en la misma pagina , podia llegar a funcionar ..

Comment: entonces si funcionaria solo que no eres muy claro al dar la informacion, explica todo el proceso

Comment: ok , a ver si encuentro algo porque hacia rato queno hacia nada con html

Comment: si, disculpas. Hace 3 horas que estaba con esto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He probado el codigo en mi equipo y funciona correctamente, iba a poner el comentario pero hasta ahora solo puedo responder.

El problema o lo que estás haciendo mal está en el codigo que tienen el boton cumplido ya que la variable `$id` no existe aun en esa parte del codigo

Esto es por que la creas dentro del `while` y por lo mismo te llega un `undefined` no le esta llegando ningun valor

Si la usas en el `while` después de asignar el $id sí te va a funcionar

```html
    <div id="fade" class="overlay"></div>
    <div id="light" class="modal">
        <p id="comentario1"></p>
        <p id="botones_alerta">
        <!-- $id no existe en esta parte del codigo -->
        <input type='button' value='Cumplido' id='cumplido' 
            onclick="cumplir_alerta(<?=$id?>);">
        <input type='button' value='Leído' id='leido' onclick="javascript:vw_nomostrar();"></p>
    </div>

    <?php
    while (($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result))!=NULL){
        // Aqui se asigna la variable $id, puedes usarla despues de esto
        $id=trim($fila['id']);             $vsocio=trim($fila['numero_socio']);
        $vcomentarios=trim($fila['observaciones']);

        // en este echo si te va a funcionar por que $id tiene un valor
        echo "<tr>\n <input type='button' value='Cumplido' onclick="cumplir_alerta(<?=$id?>);">";
   /* ... */
    }
```

**Update**

Tu problema es realmente la variable $id sin valor y puesta en donde no existe

Pero iba a sugerir lo mismo que dice @M. Gress en su respuesta, es preferible, como buenas practicas, que si estás usando jquery no uses el atributo onclick si no a traves de jQuery con `$("mi-id").click(()=>{....})`

Comment: ah claro, entiendo. Recien llego a casa y pude leer esto.  Que problema, porque yo necesito esa variable dentro del modal , o sea mas arriba, ya que lo mantengo oculto y lo muestro al hacer click en una fila de la tabla, dentro del modal visualizo el campo $vcomentarios=trim($fila['observaciones']);
 Y por debajo muestro el boton  'Cumplido' , al clickearlo llamo a un php que toma el $id por post, y realiza un Update del campo cumplido. Como podría lograr algo similar , o es imposible ?

Comment: Disculpas de nuevo  @M. Gress ! Lei con mas atención y entiendo que de como esta en tu primer respuesta debería funcionar. Estoy recreando algo similar como para probarlo pero mañana a primera hora lo pruebo en el código, gracias x la explicación .. me hacia falta

Comment: Excelente M. Gress ! Funciona increible. No se bien como se cierra esto, pero te acabo de valorar Abz !

Answer (score 0):

Bueno primero que nada tendria que sugerir que utilices algo de JavaScript para ser más preciso Jquery

En tu Modal agrega un input oculto donde deposites el ID cuando se ejecute la función **Buscar**

```
<div id="fade" class="overlay"></div>
<div id="light" class="modal">
    <p id="comentario1"></p>
    <p id="botones_alerta">
    <input type='button' value='Cumplido' id='cumplido' onclick="cumplir_alerta(<?=$id?>);">
    <input type='text' id='TuID' hidden='hidden'>
    <input type='button' value='Leído' id='leido' onclick="javascript:vw_nomostrar();"></p>
</div>
```

Esto para que cuando des click en el boton del modal puedas saber a que ID lo estas asociando en el javascript seriá algo asi:

```
function Buscar(ID)
{   
   /*Colocas el ID en el input que creamos*/
   $("#TuID").val(ID);
}

function cumplir_alerta()
{
  var ID = $("#TuID").val(); //Así obtienes el ID del input donde lo colocamos anteriormente
 /*Tu código*/
]
```